# Swift Compiler error while referencing existing variable

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, uitextview, declaration

I am trying to manually create some placeholder text for a UITextView, and when I try to set the placeholder text, I get a Swift compiler error.  Xcode is telling me that it expected a declaration for pinContent where I first try to set it's text value. Here's my code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var pinTitle: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var pinContent: UITextView!

@IBAction func createPin(sender: AnyObject) {



}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    println(userLocation)
}

// Manually create a placeholder for the text view
pinContent.text = "Description" // This line is where I get my error
pinContent.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

// Change the text properties of the text view when the user begins editing, so it types in the normal black font
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}

// If the user leaves the text view blank when they're done editing, re-set the placeholder
func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Description" // Sometimes I get the same error here as well
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Move that code into a method (e.g. into viewDidLoad) ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you want to set the text outside of the scope of a method or a closure. 
 Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Manually create a placeholder for the text view

    pinContent.text = "Description" // This line is where I get my error
    pinContent.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    println(userLocation)
}
```

Comment: Hi herby and Martin, thanks for your quick responses.  I moved the code into viewDidLoad() and now when I run the app it immediately crashes. Here's what I get in the console: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Better_Place.FirstViewController 0x7fe7e1450d60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key createPin.' Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Looks like you have a stale iboutlet definition in your storyboard. Check out if they are all wired up properly

Comment: You were right, I had a bad connection in my main.storyboard that didn't exist in my main view controller.  I went in and removed all connections and re-added them and it worked.